# How to export the sequence of outputs to excel sheet in python 3?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have the following python code which gives two sets of numerical results. I want to use the output for my computation. After each code run I copied the output manually to excel sheet that takes a lot of time. I want to export the numerical values generated by the two print commands to a single excel sheet. My code is

```
c,mu,fe,lam,r=1,1,20,0.9,0.1
LT=map(lambda x:x/fe,range(0,401))
for fg in LT:
    f=fg-(1-r)*fe
    if f<=0:
        qe=0
    else:
        if lam<=mu-c*(1-r)/f:
            qe=1
        elif mu-c*(1-r)/f<lam<=mu/r-c*(1-r)/(r*f):
            qe=(mu-lam*r)/(lam*(1-r))-c/(lam*f)
        elif mu/r-c*(1-r)/(r*f)<lam:
            qe=0
    Sqe=c*(lam*qe*(1-r)+lam*r)/(mu-lam*r-qe*lam*(1-r))
    S0=c*lam*r/(mu-lam*r)
    print("%11.6f %.6f %f %f"% (fg,qe,Sqe,S0))
import numpy as np
p=np.zeros(1002)
import math
LT=map(lambda x:x/fe,range(0,401))
for fg in LT:
    f=fg-(1-r)*fe
    rho=lam/mu
    if f<=0:
        ne=0
    else:
        ne=math.floor(mu*f/(c*(1-r)))
    if rho!=1:
        p[0]=(1-rho)*(1-r*rho)/(1-r*rho*(1-r)*rho**(ne+1))
    else:
        p[0]=1/(ne+1)
    for n in range(1,1001):
        if n<ne:
            p[n]=p[0]*rho**n
        else:
            p[n]=p[0]*rho**n*r**(n-ne)
    Sne=sum(p[n]*lam*c*(n+1)/mu for n in range(0,ne))+sum(p[n]*lam*r*c*(n+1)/mu for n in range(ne,1001))
    Sn0=sum(p[n]*lam*r*c*(n+1)/mu for n in range(0,1001))
    print("%11.6f %.6f %f %f"%(fg,ne,Sne,Sn0))
```

I am using jupyter notebook of Anaconda for python. In the code, if `LT=map(lambda x:x/fe,range(0,401))` is not written for the second time before the `second for loop`, the output is not displayed. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you want your numbers in long string form or in separate columns when you convert to excel?

Either way this is what you do:

Add

```
import pandas as pd
myList = []
```

Then, in each of your for loops, instead of printing, do:

```
myList.append("%11.6f %.6f %f %f"% (fg,qe,Sqe,S0))
```

and

```
myList.append("%11.6f %.6f %f %f"%(fg,ne,Sne,Sn0))
```

Lastly,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'OutputColumn':myList})
df.to_csv("Output.csv")
```

I suggested using dataframes because it is a great/easy solution if you want each of these #'s to be its own column, which intuitively makes more sense to me (although I am not sure what the project is). If you do use pandas, it is easy to do a lot of calculations to generate new columns and whatnot using dataframes and could eliminate your looping. If you are interested and can be more specific what you want as the code is a little confusing as an outsider I would be happy to help.

Hope this helps! If you want to continue to append to this csv there is a way to do that as well

Comment: I am getting the first set of outputs in column format and then the second set of outputs were added to the bottom of the same columns. I need the outputs in tabular form with headings as  `fg   qe ...  ne    Sne   Sn0`and the corresponding values below the headings. No need to repeat `fg` column.